# When invoking R Shiny App that uses conditional panels, how to prevent all panels from flashing by before settling on first panel?

Tags: r, shiny

Below is almost-MWE code. Issue is when opening and invoking the App, other conditional panels (tabs) flash by before settling on the first panel (tab) labeled "About". This works fine (should show "About" tab first), but everything flashing by first is sloppy. How do I keep everything from flashing by?

From my research there are cursory solutions like "place everything under renderUI" which I don't understand how to do.

Here's the MWE code (very stripped down but it illustrates the issue):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)                                     
  b <- seq(1:x)                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)                     
  return(c)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1"),
      conditionalPanel(
          condition="input.tabselected==2",
          sliderInput('periods','Input periods:',min=1,max=120,value=60),
          matrix1.input("base_input"),
          useShinyjs(),
          actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show'), 
          actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide'),
          actionButton('resetPerfVectorBtn','Reset'),
          hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))
      ) # close conditional panel
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About",value=1),
        tabPanel("Dynamic",value=2,plotOutput("graph1")), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods        <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input     <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input)

  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input", 
      value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2))})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetPerfVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix1.input("Plot"))
    }) # close render UI
  
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showPerfVectorBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    else plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving conditional panels from `ui` section to `server` section, using `ouputUI` and `renderUI`, does eliminate flash-by of other items when invoking the App, making the App appear more professional. Below is the resolved code where I take the above MWE code and move conditional panel items to `renderUI`. Please note the commented section toward the bottom under `server`, labeled "*run observeEvent in renderUI*".  I originally had that without wrapping it in `renderUI` and when moving conditional panels to `renderUI` without also wrapping that `observeEvent` in `renderUI`, the App would crash. Wrapping that `observeEvent` in `renderUI` solved the issue. It sort of makes sense to link it to `renderUI` too, but that was solution was derived through trial/error without my fully understanding why it works. I hope this doesn't cause problems later!!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(
    x,
    value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric")}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)                                     
  b <- seq(1:x)                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)                     
  return(c)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("Panels")
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About",value=1),
        tabPanel("Dynamic",value=2,plotOutput("graph1")), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  periods        <-  reactive(input$periods)
  base_input     <-  reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input)

  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==1"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','Input periods:',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showPerfVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hidePerfVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetPerfVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors")),
      ) # close conditional panel
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetPerfVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix1.input("Plot"))
  }) # close render UI
 
  # run observeEvent in renderUI
  renderUI({ 
    observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
      updateMatrixInput(session,"vector_input",
                        value=matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2))})
  }) # close renderUI
    
  observeEvent(input$showPerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hidePerfVectorBtn, {shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(
    if(input$showPerfVectorBtn == 0)
      plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1]))
    else plot(vector.base(periods(),input$base_input[1,1])))
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```